# How to get mat-tab element by id in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, getelementbyid, mat-tab

I am trying to get a mat-tab element with its id, but for some reason the command document.getElementById() returns null and not the mat-tab element. Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn5tt6

Can someone say why is this happening, and is there some better, correct way of getting the HTML-element?

Big thanks for help!

**My answer**

The best way that I found to get the tab HTML-element, was the following

HTML-file:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1
     <button (click)="printTab(tabGroup)">click me</button>
 </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

TS-file:

```
export class TabGroupBasicExample {

   @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup;

   printTab(tabGroup) {
      console.log(this.tabGroup._tabs._results[0]);
   }
}
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn5tt6-ahxi4j?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First" id="tab1"> Content 1
    <button (click)="printTab()">click me</button>
     </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The components change the HTML structure so there is no more the id in the generated HTML

If you want to find a HTMLElement you can use `mat-tab-label-0-0` for the label or `mat-tab-content-0-0` for the content.

But usually with angular you don't need to get your html element

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Element ID's are useful for testing. Relying on Material's ID declaration is not reliable. Material needs to provide a mechanism...or perhaps Angular. Consider ngId?

Answer (score 1):

Mat-Tab has id,You can call it using a function.
Add a function that calls the ids in html on click.

```
<mat-tab-group (click)="getId()">
  <mat-tab label="First" id="tab1"> Content 1
    <button (click)="printTab()">click me</button>
     </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Then in your component.ts file define the function.

```
getId(): void {
    console.log(event.srcElement.id); //mat-tab-label-1-0 on tab1
}
```